# Restrict a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I want to restrict the generic type parameter to:

1) either that of a certain user defined reference type;

OR

2) any of the primitive types in the CLR;

How do I say something to the effect of:

```
interface IDataManager<T>: IDataManager
    where T: IDataObject, T: ValueType
```

Comment: This is language dependent - is this C# ? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it is C# that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

From [Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'](http://guyellisrocks.com/coding/constraint-cannot-be-special-class-system-enum/)

> More investigation shows the C# 2.0
>   specification to have the following
>   comments on constraints:
>
> A class-type constraint must satisfy
>   the following rules:
>
> - The type must be a class type.
> - The type must not be sealed.
> - The type must not be one of the    following types: System.Array,
>     System.Delegate, System.Enum, or
>     System.ValueType.
> - The type must not be object. Because    all types derive from
>     object, such a    constraint would
>     have no effect if it    were
>     permitted.
> - At most one constraint for a given    type parameter can be a class type.

Also [Compiler Error CS0702](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56b2hk61(VS.80).aspx)

And mentioned at

[Jon Skeet: Coding Blog : Generic constraints for enums and delegates](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx)

Comment: that first link seems to have suffered from bitrot (and the skeet link too)

Comment: Please resolve edits as this is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

There's no constraint you can use that limits you to the built-in primitives.  What I would do to get around that is overload the method for each primitive, and perhaps have each overload simply pass it's argument to a private generic method that holds the common code.

Answer (score 1):

```
T: ValueType
```

The closest you can get is `T : struct`, but that wouldn't limit it only to CLR types. Either way, I don't believe there is a way to have an OR generic constraint. You could have one generic method and n-overloads for specific types.

You also can not, for example, define multiple generic functions differing only in their constraints. Constraints are not part of the signature. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx